# How do I define a sub environment in scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I am just hacking around with Scheme (mit-scheme) and I have just figured out how you change the environment, so that '+' becomes a symbol for the equivalent procedure of the '-' operator.

Example

```
(environment-define user-initial-environment '+ -)
(eval (+ 3 2) user-initial-environment)
=> 1
```

I was just wondering if there were a simple way to deal with environments as variables so when I input an environment into eval, like so

```
(eval <exp> user-initial-environment)
```

I don't have to use 'user-initial-environment'. So I can 'play' with different environments for a function.

```
(eval <exp> env)
```

Where env is some predefined environment attached to my variable 'env'.

Comment: Which implementation of Scheme are you using? I don't think there's a standard way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant MIT Scheme documentation page on [top-level environments](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Top_002dlevel-Environments.html#Top_002dlevel-Environments) could be instructive -- you can either extend an existing top-level environment (with `extend-top-level-environment`) or make a new one from scratch (with `make-top-level-environment`).

For evaluating anything but the most trivial expressions, though, it might be instructive to extend either `system-global-environment` or `user-initial-environment` (cf [13.2: Environment Variables](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables))

Comment: Thankyou, I found my answer! For the record

Comment: Thanks! For the record I went `(define env (make-top-level-environment))` and then went `(environment-define env '+ -)` then `(eval '(+ 2 2) env)` returned `0` and `(eval '(+ 2 2) user-initial-environment)` returned `4`. Interestingly `(eval (+ 2 2) env)` returned 4, and yet mit-scheme's 'eval' requires you to specify two arguments an expression to be evaluated and an environment! Why they don't just allow one argument as input to eval when evidently the second argument is superfluous when you enter the first argument unquoted.

Comment: ``eval`` is just a function, so actually ``(eval (+ 2 2) env)`` -> ``(eval 4 env)`` so no matter what environment you pass, it will not make a difference; the expression is evaluated in the current environment, *and* its result passed to ``eval`` which will have nothing more to evaluate

Answer (score 0):

With R7RS there is an `(environment)` function:

> (environment list1 ...)
> eval library procedure
> This procedure returns a specifier for the environment that
> results by starting with an empty environment and then
> importing each list, considered as an import set, into it.
> (See section 5.6 for a description of import sets.) The
> bindings of the environment represented by the specifier
> are immutable, as is the environment itself.

Page 55 in [R7RS spec](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf)